# How to avoid X-frame-options while embedding html file?

Tags: html, maven

I am using i-frame to import html file from another domain, however I get this error saying Refused to display 'url' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'. Can you please help me to avoid the exception?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overcoming "Display forbidden by X-Frame-Options"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options)

Answer (score 0):

X-Frame-Options is a HTTP Header that prevents a URL from being viewed from within an IFrame.  The only way to fix this is to change the X-Frame-Options header from the server that is serving the page you want to display within an IFrame.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

Answer (score 0):

The setting has to be done at the web-server level (apache, IIS, etc). This link will give you details on this - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

Comment: I am running my html file from intelliJ, how to do setting there?

Comment: IntelliJ is an IDE, we need to change the setting on the web server.